# update a single field of a column based on the minimum or max value of field of common rows

Tags: sql

The SQL code:

```
select * from pay_dedn_mst_st where pf_no='A044643' AND PAY_DATE='06-FEB-2013';

PF_NO   PAY_DATE  DEDN_MST_CODE DEDN_MST_AMOUNT CRNT_INST_NBR TOTAL_INST_NBR USERID    LAST_UPDA
------- --------- ------------- --------------- ------------- -------------- --------- ---------
A044643 06-FEB-13           122             100                              PN        07-MAR-13

A044643 06-FEB-13            21             444            21             60 PN        07-MAR-13

A044643 06-FEB-13            21            6667            21             60 PN        07-MAR-13

A044643 06-FEB-13             4             300             2             10 PN        07-MAR-13

A044643 06-FEB-13            61            1340             4              5 PN        07-MAR-13
```

I have 2 rows of same DEDN_MST_CODE,i.e. 21.How can i update DEDN_MST_CODE and set it to 47 for the least DEDN_MST_AMOUNT in DEDN_MST_CODE 21.

Comment: What is the primary key of this table?

Comment: Also, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: pay date isn't really a string is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE pay_dedn_mst_st
SET DEDN_MST_CODE = 47
FROM (SELECT MIN(DEDN_MST_AMOUNT) as amount
      FROM pay_dedn_mst_st
      WHERE pf_no='A044643' AND PAY_DATE='06-FEB-2013'
        AND DEDN_MST_CODE = 21) t
WHERE pf_no='A044643' AND PAY_DATE='06-FEB-2013'
  AND DEDN_MST_CODE = 21 AND DEDN_MST_AMOUNT = t.amount
```